# Groovy Parsing JSON in Jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to read from a rest API in a jenkins script.  My code looks like this

```
script
    {
        def url = "https://myurl" 
        def get = new URL(url).openConnection();
        def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
                
        echo "Response Code" + getRC;
        if(getRC.equals(200)) {
            def response =   get.getInputStream().getText();
            echo "text: " + response;
            def content = response.get("RA")
        }
}
```

When I run this I get

```
Response Code200
text: {"RA":"CHAN-1234"}
```

I just need to get the last line working,  i.e set content equal to value for RA (i.e. CHAN-1234)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not parsing the json. use `readJSON` pipeline step or `JsonSlurperClassic` class to parse json

Comment: Thanks @daggett,  I had actually already tried both of those.  The above code was like my 50th attempt at getting it to work.   In the end, I updated the relevant Jenkins plugins & restarted.  Then suddenly readJSON started to work correctly.